# Joint effort limits and realistic behavior

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

So I'm done with the description of my robot and I'm not satisfied with the final result. The movements are far from what I have seen on the videos. The description is based on values provided by the manufacturer.

One of my assumption is that I do not understand the "joint limit effort" value. I have used the torque value given for the actuators. The robot looks too weak to move properly. What value should be used for this?

Additional remark. According to the wiki, this information is mandatory for revolute joints, but it has not been defined for the [rrbot](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/blob/master/rrbot_description/urdf/rrbot.xacro).

Link to the URDF wiki, [here](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint).

This is a first assumption and I may post a more general question later.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4574/joint-effort-limits-and-realistic-behavior/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 316 on 2013-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The effort limit is the maximum effort a ROS controller will apply to a joint. If your are using ROS to control your robot and you have this value set too low, then the joint in question may not have the "strength" to move.

Another possible problem is bad PID values defined for your ROS controllers.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2014-04-16**:
@nkoenig does gazebo impose any limits on joints? for e.g. in the gazebo gui, right most panel, we cannot apply force greater than 1000Nm. For a heavy platform, how can we apply high values?